# Disabling fprintd.service prevents boot; How to restore boot?

Tags: boot, systemd, services, 22.04

I've discovered that disabling fprintd.service prevents Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 from booting.

Specifically, a number of [DEPEND] dependency failures scroll rapidly past the screen in tty1, too fast to read but that appear to be mount units failing for want of a dependency, and the boot process stops with

```
[  OK  ] Reached Target Printer Support
```

This is in a multiboot setting, so I booted to another Ubuntu partition and deleted the symlink masking the service, at least, but the same boot hang exists.

I also tried to chroot into the partition while booted to stick, to enable the service but the command failed by reason of being in a chroot environment.

The question is, how can one get this machine to boot?

EDIT:  The bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fprintd/+bug/1975660).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, frankly, don't think the reason for the system not booting is disabling or even masking `fprintd.service`, it doesn't have that sort of influence ... most likely something else you did.

Anyway, to re-enable it or any `systemd` service for the matter, please see below.

#### One way

`systemd.mask=ServiceName.service` and `systemd.wants=ServiceName.service` are two [Kernel Command Line Arguments](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html) that can be used to respectively disable and enable `systemd` services during boot (runtime). These can be added as [Kernel Boot Parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) to GRUB during boot.

In your case, it's good that you managed to delete the symlink masking the service file so now you can temporarily enable the service during the next boot by adding `systemd.wants=fprintd.service` kernel boot parameter from the GRUB menu.

#### Another way

1. Boot to [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).
2. Drop to root shell.
3. Mount your root file system as read and write like so:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
4. Unmask the service like so:

   ```
   systemctl unmask fprintd.service
   ```
5. Enable the service like so:

   ```
   systemctl enable fprintd.service
   ```
6. Reboot your system.

Comment: thanks.  I'm marking this as the accepted answer because it addresses the question squarely.  Two things, though.  (a) I isolated the cause in debugging an install script, stepwise disabling candidate units and immediately rebooting.  This unit triggered the hang.  A bug report has been filed (see above). (b) It turns out another solution to this particular service and package is to delete all files containing 'fprintd' in their name.  I'll post this presently.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered another approach, which may apply only to this package and service.

Simply deleting all files on the filesystem with names containing the string 'fprintd' allows the system to boot.

While booted to Ubuntu on another partition (one also could do this while booted to stick), I simply opened the problem partition's root as Administrator in Nautilus, searched for all files containing 'fprintd', highlighted / selected them all, and deleted them.  I immediately initiated a reboot, which was successful.

This is clearly inelegant and facile, leaving many questions unanswered for the time being, but it solved the immediate problem of getting the machine to boot.